# Convert a set of rows into a new column in sql

Tags: sql

I am working on a report for which I need an SQL query which changes the following:

```
DATABASE    SCHEMA   Table Name   Rows
A             1            X        12
B             1            X        32
A             2            X        10
B             2            X        22
A             3            Y        14
B             3            Y        21
A             4            Z        33
B             4            Z        33
```

to something like this:

```
SCHEMA     TABLE    A - Rows    B - Rows
  1          X         12          32
  2          X         10          22
  3          Y         14          21
  4          Z         33          33
```

There are multiple entries for the same table in both the databases which is why I'm not able to figure it out. Can someone help me out with this.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are not the same. Which are you using (Edit your tags and remove the wrong one)? Also, what is the query you are using to generate the data in your initial dataset?

Comment: Your data has no examples of "multiple entries for the same table in both databases".  Please provide examples of such data and what the results should be.  I also removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data suggests *conditional* aggregation :

```
select SCHEMA, table_name, 
       sum(case when db_name = 'A' then rows else 0 end) as A_row,
       sum(case when db_name = 'B' then rows else 0 end) as B_row,
       . . .
from table t
group by SCHEMA, table_name;
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helped. Can conditional aggregation also work with another constraint? I have edited the questions and added a new column - 'schema' such a way that two schemas can have the same table name.

Comment: @S.A.. . . Add the `Schema` in `GROUP BY` clause. See EDIT.